# Cash Deposit in Sparkasse Bank

Tags: cash

I have a bank account at the Sparkasse (A German Bank). I have some cash, Can I deposit in the Bank Branches, even if I only have an ATM Card? Which charges are applicable and maximum how much cash I can deposit, since I am a student and earned some money working in leisure time?

Comment: Is this about a German Sparkasse?

Comment: It is difficult to see what your question is.

Comment: Especially given that (a) banks have cash counters and (b) being a customer of a bank,TALKING TO YOUR ACCOUNT MANAGER is normally the best way to get trivial answers.

Comment: I edited after seeing votes to reopen. Can you confirm this was the intent of your question?

Comment: @TomTom Having used various banks for years. I have absolutely no idea what an account manager is or how one would talk to one?